# how to obtain date month of a variable containing next monday

Tags: shell, date

I'm able to have the date of next monday like this

```
date --date="next monday" +"%d"
```

however now I have next monday in a variable `${dayToStopString}` and I want to set the result in `dayToStop`

```
dayToStop=`date --date=${dayToStopString} +"%d"`
```

it works when `dayToStopString` is tomorrow, but not when it's two days word

I tried many things like

```
dayToStop=`date --date=\"${dayToStopString}\" +"%d"`
dayToStop=`date --date=\'${dayToStopString}\' +"%d"`
```

and others with no success. I found solutions in forums, but only by giving the word directly "next monday"

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape the quotes around `${dayToStopString}`? You don't do that for the quotes around `%d`.

Comment: haha true.. now it works!! I thought that because when it's yesterday I didn't need to put them... so it confuses me since for next monday I need them
thx a lot